# Converting Google maps dynamic and resizing circle v2 to v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

http://web3o.blogspot.in/2010/05/google-maps-dynamically-movable-and.html

From the above link i got V2 google maps code which is working fine, but not able to import V3 beach markers so i convert the draw circle, circle resize and circle center marker function to V3 and i am not getting the circle in the maps where as i am getting all the marker, beach marker flags etc.

Following is the code, Kindly help me in fixing this, save the code as HTML file and execute in the browser.

I am having **issue** in the **drawCircle function** were the **circle is not drawn** on the **Map**.

```
 <!--<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyDAAkI8Q59oV68_F8r8hL66vlhCu9cWNQM&sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
/* Developed by: Abhinay Rathore [web3o.blogspot.com] */ 
//Global variables 
var map; 

var circle = [];

//circle[0] = {map_center: new GLatLng(38.903843, -94.680096),
//            }; 

var Cobj = [];//{'mp_center':


var frndmap = [];

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds; //Circle Bounds 

var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(12.9735597, 77.6410402);

frndmap = [['Mahesh Pusala', 12.9735521, 77.6410431, 1], ['Bala Sundar', 12.9735567, 77.6410489, 2]];

var Circle=[];//null,null];//Circle object 
var CirclePoints = []; //Circle drawing points 
var CircleCenterMarker, CircleResizeMarker = [];//null,null]; 
var circle_moving = false; //To track Circle moving 
var circle_resizing = false; //To track Circle resizing 
var radius = []; //1 km 
//var min_radius = 0.5; //0.5km 
//var max_radius = 50; //5km 

//Circle Marker/Node icons 
/*var redpin = new google.maps.MarkerImage(); //Red Pushpin Icon 
redpin.image = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-pushpin.png"; 
redpin.iconSize = new google.maps.Size(32, 32); 
redpin.iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(10, 32);*/
var redpin = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-pushpin.png',
// This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
  new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
  // The origin for this image is 0,0.
  new google.maps.Point(0,0),
  // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
  new google.maps.Point(10, 32));

/*var bluepin = new google.maps.MarkerImage(); //Blue Pushpin Icon 
bluepin.image = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-pushpin.png"; 
bluepin.iconSize = new google.maps.Size(32, 32); 
bluepin.iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(10, 32);*/
var bluepin = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-pushpin.png',
// This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
  new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
  // The origin for this image is 0,0.
  new google.maps.Point(0,0),
  // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
  new google.maps.Point(10, 32));

function initialize() { //Initialize Google Map
        //for(c in circle) {

        //map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas")); //New GMap object

        var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: map_center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


        /*addCircleResizeMarker(map_center[0], '0'); 

        addCircleCenterMarker(map_center[0],'0'); 
       drawCircle(map_center[0], radius, '0'); 

        addCircleCenterMarker(map_center[1],'1'); 
        addCircleResizeMarker(map_center[1], '1');
         drawCircle(map_center[1], radius, '1'); 
*/

for(i=0; i<3; i++) {

    Cobj[i] = {'map_center':new google.maps.LatLng(12.9735597+i, 77.6410402+i),
        'Circle':null,
        'CircleResizeMarker':null,
        'radius':24+i
    };

    addCircleCenterMarker(i); 
    addCircleResizeMarker(i);
    drawCircle(Cobj[i].map_center,Cobj[i].radius, i); 
}


 map.setCenter(map_center);
 setMarkers(map, frndmap);
} 

// Adds Circle Center marker 


//radius

function addCircleCenterMarker(iii) { 
    point = Cobj[iii].map_center;
    var markerOptions = { icon: bluepin, draggable: true }; 
    CircleCenterMarker = new google.maps.Marker(point, markerOptions); 
    CircleCenterMarker.setMap(map); //Add marker on the map 
    //X= new google.maps.event();
    google.maps.event.addListener(CircleCenterMarker, 'dragstart', function() { //Add drag start event 
        circle_moving = true; 
    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(CircleCenterMarker, 'drag', function(point) { //Add drag event 
        drawCircle(point,Cobj[iii].radius, iii); 
    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(CircleCenterMarker, 'dragend', function(point) { //Add drag end event 
console.log(point.lng());
        circle_moving = false; 
        drawCircle(point, Cobj[iii].radius, iii); 
    }); 
} 

// Adds Circle Resize marker 


// map_center
function addCircleResizeMarker(iii) { 
    point = Cobj[iii].map_center;
    var resize_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(redpin); 
    resize_icon.maxHeight = 0; 
    var markerOptions = { icon: resize_icon, draggable: true }; 
    Cobj[iii].CircleResizeMarker = new google.maps.Marker(point, markerOptions); 
    Cobj[iii].CircleResizeMarker.setMap(map); //Add marker on the map 
    google.maps.event.addListener(Cobj[iii].CircleResizeMarker, 'dragstart', function() { //Add drag start event 
        circle_resizing = true; 
    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(Cobj[iii].CircleResizeMarker, 'drag', function(point) { //Add drag event 
        var new_point = new google.maps.LatLng(Cobj[iii].map_center.lat(), point.lng()); //to keep resize marker on horizontal line 
        var new_radius = new_point.distanceFrom(Cobj[iii].map_center) / 1000; //calculate new radius 
        //if (new_radius < min_radius) new_radius = min_radius; 
        //if (new_radius > max_radius) new_radius = max_radius; 
        drawCircle(Cobj[iii].map_center, new_radius, iii); 
    }); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(Cobj[iii].CircleResizeMarker, 'dragend', function(point) { //Add drag end event 
        circle_resizing = false; 
        var new_point = new google.maps.LatLng(Cobj[iii].map_center.lat(), point.lng()); //to keep resize marker on horizontal line 
        var new_radius = new_point.distanceFrom(Cobj[iii].map_center) / 1000; //calculate new radius 
        //if (new_radius < min_radius) new_radius = min_radius; 
        //if (new_radius > max_radius) new_radius = max_radius; 
console.log(new_radius);
        drawCircle(Cobj[iii].map_center, new_radius, iii); 
    }); 
} 

//Draw Circle with given radius and center 
function drawCircle(center,new_radius, iii) { 

//Circle = Circle[iii];
    //Circle Drawing Algorithm from: http://koti.mbnet.fi/ojalesa/googlepages/circle.htm 

    //Number of nodes to form the circle 
    var nodes = new_radius * 40; 
    if(new_radius < 1) nodes = 40; 

    //calculating km/degree 

    xx = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat() + 0.1, center.lng());
    yy = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat() , center.lng()+0.1);

    var latConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(center,xx)/100;//center.distanceFrom(new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat() + 0.1, center.lng())) / 100; 
    var lngConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(center,yy)/100;//center.distanceFrom(new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat(), center.lng() + 0.1)) / 100; 

    CirclePoints = []; 
    var step = parseInt(360 / nodes) || 10; 
    var counter = 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i <= 360; i += step) { 
        var cLat = center.lat() + (new_radius / latConv * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 180)); 
        var cLng = center.lng() + (new_radius / lngConv * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180)); 
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(cLat, cLng); 
        CirclePoints.push(point); 
        counter++; 
    }

    Cobj[iii].CircleResizeMarker.setPosition(CirclePoints[Math.floor(counter / 4)]); //place circle resize marker 
    CirclePoints.push(CirclePoints[0]); //close the circle polygon 
    if (Cobj[iii].Circle) { 
    //map.removeOverlay(Cobj[iii].Circle); 
    marker.setMap(null);
    } //Remove existing Circle from Map 
    var fillColor = (circle_resizing || circle_moving) ? 'red' : 'blue'; //Set Circle Fill Color
    console.log(CirclePoints);
    Cobj[iii].Circle = new google.maps.Polygon(CirclePoints, '#FF0000', 2, 1, fillColor, 0.2); //New GPolygon object for Circle 
    //Cobj[iii].Circle.setMap(map); //Add Circle Overlay on the Map 
    //radius = new_radius; //Set global radius 
    //Cobj[iii].map_center = center; //Set global map_center 
    //if (!circle_resizing && !circle_moving) 
    //{ 
        //Fit the circle if it is nor moving or resizing 
    // fitCircle(Cobj[iii].Circle); 
        //Circle drawing complete trigger function goes here 
    //} 
} 

//Fits the Map to Circle bounds 
function fitCircle(Circle) { 
    bounds = Circle.getBounds(); 
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));   
}

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  // Add markers to the map

  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
  // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
  // in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
  // increase in the X direction to the right and in
  // the Y direction down.
  var image = {
    url: 'images/beachflag.png',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };
  var shadow = {
    url: 'images/beachflag_shadow.png',
    // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
    // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
    size: new google.maps.Size(37, 32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };
  // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
  // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
  // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
  // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
  // coordinate.
  var shape = {
      coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
      type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var beach = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: beach[0],
        zIndex: beach[3]
    });
  }
}
</script>

<body onload="initialize()"> 
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:450px"></div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your drawCircle function has

```
Cobj[iii].Circle = new google.maps.Polygon(CirclePoints, '#FF0000', 2, 1, fillColor, 0.2); //New GPolygon object for Circle
```

Personally I'd rather use google.maps.Circle instead, much simpler
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle